# Code to select dropdown menu option executing but not working with Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a dropdown menu and select the first option.  Occasionally, I am able to write code that will work, but when I run the full script, it fails.  That is, the code executes, but it does not make a selection in the dropdown menu.  Eventually however, all code that worked initially fails to work subsequently.  Sometimes the error is "ElementClickInterceptedException" and sometimes the element can't be found.

Here is the element of the dropdown menu:

```
<span class="mat-select-placeholder ng-tns-c37-1395 ng-star-inserted">ORCA Review Result</span>
```

However, there is an arrow in the dropdown menu that has the following element:

```
<div class="mat-select-arrow"></div>
```

Now using my keyboard, I can make the selection by pressing enter after the dropdown menu has been clicked.  This can be mimicked by ActionChains, but although this approach worked initially, it no longer works.

As an alternative method, I have tried to click on the dropdown menu option, and I suspect that a new element needs to be specified in order to do this.  So, here's the element associated with the menu option I want to click.

```
<span class="mat-option-text"> Accepted </span>
```

Please help.  This is completely blowing my mind.